# Sorting custom taxonomy term page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type for a product with two custom taxonomies, "colour" and "style". Products are tagged in both of these. When you go to the taxonomy term page it works as it should i.e. if you go to `/colour/blue` it lists all blue products.

What I want to happen is when you go to `/colour/blue` is lists all blue products BUT groups them by the second taxonomy "style" showing the first three products with a read more link.

So

> Blue > Product Style 1

- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3

See More..

> Blue > Product Style 2

- Product 3
- Product 4
- Product 5

See More..

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Current code is this, I've created a taxonomy template for the term taxonomy-colour.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main role="main" class="blinds">

    <h1 class="main-product-title">Products</h1>

    <!-- section -->
    <section class="main-product-content">

        <h2><?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); echo $term->name; ?></h2>

        <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <!-- article -->
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <!-- post image -->
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>

                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(720,400)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- /post thumbnail -->

                <!-- post title -->
                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                <!-- /post title -->

                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">View ></a></p>

            </article>

            <!-- /article -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else: ?>

            <!-- article -->
            <article>
                <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
            </article>
            <!-- /article -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>

    </section>
    <!-- /section -->

    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('product-sidebar')) ?>
    </div>

</main>
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Hi there, I have created a template for the taxonomy which is taxonomy-colour.php and put that above.

Comment: I have answered similar before, either here or on [wordpress.se], just can't remember where, but in essence, you need to use the `the_posts` filter and resort the posts with `usort()`

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at the_posts filter and see if I can apply that to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, you need to use `usort()` on the `the_posts` filter to sort your posts according to needs.

You can try the following: (***NOTE:*** The following code is untested and requires PHP 5.4+ due to array dereferencing)

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', function ( $posts, $q ) 
{
    if (    $q->is_main_query() // Target only the main query
          && $q->is_tax( 'colour' ) // Only target the colour taxonomy term pages
    ) {
        /**
         * There is a bug in usort that will most probably never get fixed. In some instances
         * the following PHP warning is displayed 

         * usort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function
         * @see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50688

         * The only workaround is to suppress the error reporting
         * by using the @ sign before usort
         */      
        @usort( $posts, function ( $a, $b )
        {
            // Use term name for sorting. We will sort by style taxonomy term
            $array_a = get_the_terms( $a->ID, 'style' );
            $array_b = get_the_terms( $b->ID, 'style' );

            // Add protection if posts don't have any terms, add them last in queue
            if ( empty( $array_a ) || is_wp_error( $array_a ) ) {
                $array_a = 'zzz'; // Make sure to add posts without terms last
            } else {
                $array_a = $array_a[0]->name;
            }

            // Add protection if posts don't have any terms, add them last in queue
            if ( empty( $array_b ) || is_wp_error( $array_b ) ) {
                $array_b = 'zzz'; // Make sure to add posts without terms last
            } else {
                $array_b = $array_b[0]->name;
            }

            /**
             * Sort by term name, if term name is the same sort by post date
             * You can adjust this to sort by post title or any other WP_Post property_exists
             */
            if ( $array_a != $array_b ) { 
                // Choose the one sorting order that fits your needs
                return strcasecmp( $array_a, $array_b ); // Sort term alphabetical ASC 
                //return strcasecmp( $array_b, $array_a ); // Sort term alphabetical DESC
            } else {
                return $a->post_date < $b->post_date; // Not sure about the comparitor, also try >
            }
        });
    }
    return $posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You should start a new question with the new info. Limiting your posts will have nothing to do with this code, you will need to filter the main query with `pre_get_posts`

Answer (score -1):

The first thing to do is to get the available *style* terms for your current taxonomy term. For that you can get all the posts IDs of your current taxonomy then get the *style* terms from them using [`wp_get_object_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms). Then you loop through them, query three posts that have  both of those taxonomy terms (*colour* and *style*).

Here is an example that you can use for your case:

```
<?php
// get the term...
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

// get all posts from this term and store the IDs
$term_posts = get_posts(array('tax_query' => array(array(
    'taxonomy' => get_query_var('taxonomy'),
    'terms' => $term->ID
))));
$term_posts_IDs = array();
foreach ($term_posts as $term_post) {
    $term_posts_IDs[] = $term_post->ID;
}

// get the available styles from this set of posts
$styles = wp_get_object_terms($term_posts_IDs, 'style');

?>
<h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
<?php 
if(!empty($styles)): // styles are availables for this term
    foreach($styles as $style):
        ?>
        <h3><?php echo $term->name; ?> &gt; <?php echo $style->name; ?></h3>
        <?php
        // get the first three products with colour + style
        $tax_posts = get_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => get_query_var('taxonomy'),
                    'terms' => $term->ID
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'style',
                    'terms' => $style->ID
                )
            )
        ));
        ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach($tax_posts as $tax_post): ?>
            <li><?php echo $tax_post->post_title; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <!-- ... link to your style taxonomy template here ... -->
    <?pgpp endforeach ; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <!-- ... default behaviour ... -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

You'll have to build your read more link by sending the *style* term **and** the *colour* term to your *style* taxonomy template.

Comment: This is extremely ineffecient, ***why*** are you running custom queries

Comment: @PieterGoosen I'm all open to see your answer about this question, but sadly I *don't* see any.

Comment: I will post something later tonight. It is a nightmare coding something like this on a mobile phone. ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen I found a post of yours similar (link posted below ) but I am still confused and can't apply it to my problem. Are you able to provide a solution? :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381726/grouping-wordpress-custom-posts-by-taxonomy/31388018#31388018

Comment: I have stripped and modified that code. I have not tested it, but you should get the idea. Note, you will need PHP 5.4+ @user1837290

Comment: Thank you @PieterGoosen that is amazing much appreciated! Works a treat. Do you happen to know how I would go about limiting it to showing the first three products per style? I presume the filter needs some sort of counter on it with an if statement? I have my view more link and everything else working great.

Comment: Lets move this to my answer and respect other answers :-)